# How would I link the two classes together to show the one to many relationship between Person and Address

Tags: java, class, oop

Address class:

```java
public class Address {

    private String country;
    private String county;
    private String city;
    private String postcode;
    private String HouseNumber;

    public Address(String country, String county, String city, String postcode, String HouseNumber) {
        this.country = country;
        this.county = county;
        this.city = city;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.HouseNumber = HouseNumber;
    }

    public void view_adress() {
        String[] address = {country, county, city, postcode, HouseNumber};
        
        for (int i = 0; i<address.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(address[i]);
        }
    }
                
    public void viewHouseNumber() {
        System.out.print(HouseNumber);
    }
}
```

Person class:

```java
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String Date_of_birth;
    private String PhoneNumber;
    private String[] address;
    
    public Person (String firstName, String lastName, String Date_of_birth, String PhoneNumber, String[] address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.Date_of_birth = Date_of_birth;
        this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void view_PhoneNumber() {
        System.out.print(PhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, spare the readers and format/clean your code.

Comment: There is actually a many-to-many relationship between people and adresses, in the real world.

Comment: Note that you should normally avoid using arrays; `List` is better because it automatically manages size and has other features. Additionally, your code will be easier to read if you follow code standards: Members should be `camelCase`, not `TitleCase` (`PhoneNumber`) or `snake_case`.

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for the right insight. I've added that information as well.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of OOP [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

```java
public class Person {
    //...
    List<Address> addresses;
    //...
}
```

One instance of a `Person` will have a 0 or more instances of `Address`.

Note, that in a real world scenario, you better want to retain a list of `userId`s in your `Address` class as well, because, *more-than-one* users, might have one, or also *more-than-one* addresses, which means, that that your relation must be `Many-To-Many`.

No less (at all) important thing it to stick with the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) and name:

- classes with `PascalCase`;
- fields and method names with `camelCase`;
- constants with `ALL_CAPS_SEPARATED_WITH_UNDERSCORES`.

Comment: Would that then remove the need for the attribute private String[] address

Comment: You have an `Address` type. Why would you want to have a `String[] address;` instead? do you want to store addresses as string literals? using a discrete/separate type (`Address`) is a way better idea in this case, rather than storing your address(es) as a string literals. So, yes, `String[] address` seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: I'm quite new to Java!

Comment: Just change your `private String[] address;` with `private List<Address> addresses;`. N. B. please follow the Java naming conventions: Do not start your variable identifiers with a first capital character (which you have in several occasions). Also, make your field names descriptive. E.g. when you store a List of objects, it's probably better to name the field as *addresses*.

Comment: I will repost the question I've changed the class person to a different format would this still work.

Comment: Please do not repost the question if it is an answer, use rather comments to discuss something further. Have a look on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here.

Comment: When using the private list<Address> addresses attribute would that allow for multiple instances of the Address class to be passed to it?

Comment: How does that differ from using the Private Addresses addresses;

Comment: I would recommend you to stop writing whatever code/project you're writing now, and go back to learn Java SE core concepts, namely (in this context) - [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).